# Quadrature of $\int_{-2}^2 e^{-x} f(x) dx$ by $\alpha_0f(-1) + \alpha_1f(0) + \alpha_2f(1)$

Tags: numerical-methods, quadratics

I am looking for an approximation 
$$\alpha_0f(-1) + \alpha_1f(0) + \alpha_2f(1)$$
of
$$\int_{-2}^2 e^{-x} f(x) dx $$
that is exact for polynomials $f$ of degree 2.

My first idea is to solve these equations for the polynomials $1$, $x$ and $x^2$.

$$ \int_{-2}^2 e^{-x} dx = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 $$
$$ \int_{-2}^2 e^{-x} x dx = -\alpha_0 + \alpha_2 $$
$$ \int_{-2}^2 e^{-x} x^2 dx = \alpha_0 + \alpha_2 $$

I believe that should work. I have a feeling, though, that I am missing a much more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of $e^{-x}$, there is no symmetry to exploit. Since the coefficients give you the value of integrals such as $\int x^2 e^{-x}\,dx$, having a ridiculously easy way to find them would revolutionalize the teaching of integral calculus. This is unlikely. 
I would write 
$$
\begin{split}
\alpha_0 &= \frac12 \int_{-2}^2 e^{-x}(x^2-x)\,dx \\ 
\alpha_1 &= \int_{-2}^2 e^{-x}(1-x^2)\,dx \\ 
\alpha_2 &= \frac12 \int_{-2}^2 e^{-x}(x^2+x)\,dx 
\end{split}
$$
and outsource the boring parts to a computer, for example [this is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20exp%28-x%29*%28x%5E2%2Bx%29%2F2%20from%20-2%20to%202) the computation of $\alpha_2$.

Comment: For $f(x)=x$ I get $\alpha_0 f(-1) + \alpha_1 f(0) + \alpha_2 f(1)$ = $-\alpha_0 + \alpha_2$. Probably you evaluated f at $-2$, $0$ and $2$ or am I overlooking something else?

Comment: @Niklas Hm, I actually typed the answer correctly the first time, and that changed to incorrect version. Rolled back now.